# How do I log the response size in byte in Node.js / (unjs) h3 / Nuxt v3?

Tags: logging, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

**EDIT** I'm aware there's a response header called Content-Length but no response headers are set yet at the point where this middleware runs at.

I'm trying to make my Nuxt v3 application log properly in using the [Combined Log Format](http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Combined_Log_Format) and one of the fields is the response size in bytes. This is the middleware I'm using, but I fear this is way too early to know this value, and in fact I can't find anything in the `event.res` object that resembles a size in bytes.

```js
import { CompatibilityEvent } from "h3";
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

export default defineEventHandler((event: CompatibilityEvent) => {
    const ip = event.req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];
    const date = DateTime.now().setLocale('en-US').toFormat('[dd/LLL/yyyy:TT ZZZ]');
    const method = event.req.method || '-';
    const path = event.req.url || '-';
    const httpVersion = event.req.httpVersion;
    const statusCode = event.res.statusCode || '-';
    const referer = event.req.headers['referer'];
    const agent = event.req.headers["user-agent"];

    console.log(`${ip} - - ${date} "${method} ${path} HTTP/${httpVersion}" ${statusCode} - "${referer}" "${agent}"`);
})
```

And this produces stuff the likes of

```
192.168.1.11 - - [17/Aug/2022:22:21:33 +0200] "GET /cv HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://192.168.1.11:3000/cv" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

which is correct, except that the dash right after the status code should be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this question searching for the same answer. Sorry I've no experience with Nuxt but hopefully this will help.

I solved it using `response._contentLength`

In the middleware, I waited for the `response.on('finish')` event, then accessed `_contentLength`

```js
app.use((request, response, next) => {
    response.on('finish', () => {
        console.log(response._contentLength);
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: Interesting. That field is not documented as part of `ServerResponse` (probably private?). It took some gymnastics to get TypeScript to let me fish it out, and it still comes out as `undefined` from time to time, but it's good enough. Thanks!